# Can [DllImport(“ ”)] , DLL without error after using protector software C# Winform

Tags: c#, c++, c, winforms

I am using a C# WinForm. I have an unmanaged DLL (`nip.dll`), and I put it in the same directory.

After using protector software (Obfuscator) , these characters are not "snip.dll" and cannot import the DLL.

Is there any solution? Or, can I do that using another language, such as C++?

```cs
[DllImport(@"nip.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateInstance")]
static extern IntPtr nip_ctor(uint pID);

public nip(int pID)
{
    //pInstance = nip_ctor((uint)pID);

    try
    {
        pInstance = nip_ctor((uint)pID);
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR DLL");
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: By any chance with "protector software" do you mean an obfuscator?

Comment: yes, after using obfuscator (protector software), the character "snip.dll" is changed to encoded characters, is there any way for me to import unmanaged dlls please give me an idea

Comment: Why do you want to abfuscate a wrapper for an external *.dll? So nobody should see the wrapped fuction calls or what's the intention?

Comment: Your obfuscation software must have some kind of control on what is or is not obfuscated, disable string obfuscation or reduce agresiveness. If that doesn't works call to the support service of the program you are using, it's a problem with that software, it has nothing to do with C# or .net